# How to use sscanf to store variables in a line from a file?

Tags: c, scanf

I want to scan and store the variables in this line: 
`11.0.0.0, 255.0.0.0, 10.1.0.1, eth9` as `netId`, `netMask`, `gateway` and `interface`

Using `sscanf(buff1,"%s %s %s %s",netId,netMask,Gateway,Iface);` I'm able to store these variables but how can I store these variables when there is a comma(`,`) as mentioned in the above example?

Comment: `sscanf(buff1,"%s, %s, %s, %s",netId,netMask,Gateway,Iface);` how about this?

Comment: @haris: that won't work; the `,` in the data is read as a perfectly good 'not a white space character' and included in the string, and then there isn't a comma left in the input to match the literal comma in the format string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to identify what you want carefully.  It is harder than you'd like, but it can be done.  The trouble with `%s` is that it reads up to the first white space character.  The comma is not white space, so it will be included in the string scanned by `%s`, and then there isn't a comma left in the input to match the comma in the format string.  So, you need to look for a sequence of 'not commas'.  That's a 'scan set'.

```
if (sscanf(buff1," %[^,], %[^,], %[^,], %s", netId, netMask, Gateway, Iface) != 4)
    …data was malformed…
```

The leading white space in the format skips optional leading spaces in the input string, like `%s` would skip leading white space.

---

As [Zack](https://stackoverflow.com/users/388520/zack) notes in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26654441/how-to-use-sscanf-to-store-variables-in-a-line-from-a-file/26655089?noredirect=1#comment41917078_26655089), this code does not protect you from buffer overflows.  Since you didn't show the definitions of any of the variables, it is not possible to know whether this is an issue or not.  If you have:

```
char buff1[64];
char netId[64];
char netMask[64];
char Gateway[64];
char Iface[64];
```

then clearly none of the individual fields can be larger than the input buffer and overflow is not possible.  OTOH, if the individual fields are smaller than the buffer,  Zack is right that you could overflow the buffers.

There are (at least) two ways to avoid that problem.  First, assuming each of the target buffers is 16 bytes long (instead of 64 as shown above), then this modified code would be safe:

```
if (sscanf(buff1," %15[^,], %15[^,], %15[^,], %15s",
           netId, netMask, Gateway, Iface) != 4)
    …data was malformed…
```

This could still leave some bytes at the end of the buffer after the `Iface` element, but is otherwise safe.  Note that the size specified in the conversion specification is one less than the size in the data definition; this allows for the null terminator.

The alternative uses a POSIX
[`sscanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sscanf.html)
feature: the `m` 'assignment allocation' modifier.  In this case, you pass a pointer to a `char *` to `scanf()` and it allocates the correct amount of memory:

```
char *netId = 0;
char *netMask = 0;
char *Gateway = 0;
char *Iface = 0;

if (sscanf(buff1," %m[^,], %m[^,], %m[^,], %ms",
           &netId, &netMask, &Gateway, &Iface) != 4)
    …data was malformed…

free(netId);
free(netMask);
free(Gateway);
free(Iface);
```

Note that if a conversion fails, all memory allocated by the `m` modifier is freed before `sscanf()` returns.  However, it is not guaranteed that if the third allocation fails, the pointers for the first and second allocations are unchanged.  Thus, you should not free any of the allocated memory if the overall conversion fails.

Comment: You should show how to prevent `sscanf` from overrunning the destination buffer.  As written, this construct is every bit as dangerous as `gets`.

Answer (score 1):

You should not do this with `sscanf`, because you should never use `*scanf` for anything.  There are several reasons for this; the immediately relevant ones are that it's impossible to do error recovery reliably with `*scanf`, and the `%s` and `%[...]` format descriptors can be used without specifying the size of the destination buffer, making them just as dangerous as the infamous `gets`.

I would personally do this with hand-rolled code of the general form

```
char *p = buf, *q;
for (q = p; *q && *q != ','; q++) {}
if (!*q) syntax_error();
*q = '\0';
netId = strdup(p);

p = q+1;
while (*p == ' ' || *p == '\t') p++; 
for (q = p; *q && *q != ','; q++) {}
if (!*q) syntax_error();
*q = '\0';
netMask = strdup(p);

// etc
```

There are functions in the standard library (e.g. `strsep` and `strchr`) that *seem* like they can improve on the above, but if you actually try to use them you discover that they don't make your code any shorter or easier to read.

On a POSIX system, another reasonable option is the `regex.h` interfaces:

```
// ERROR HANDLING OMITTED FOR BREVITY

// outside the loop
regex_t linere;
regcomp(&linere, 
        "^([0-9.]+),[ \t]*([0-9.]+),[ \t]*([0-9.]+),[ \t]*([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$",
        REG_EXTENDED);

// inside the loop
regmatch_t rm[5];
regexec(&linere, buf, 5, rm, 0);

netId = malloc(rm[1].rm_eo - rm[1].rm_so + 1);
memcpy(netId, buf + rm[1].rm_so, rm[1].rm_eo - rm[1].rm_so);
netId[rm[1].rm_eo - rm[1].rm_so] = '\0';

// etc
```

If the parsing job is even a little tiny bit more complicated than this it may be time to reach for `lex` and `yacc`.

Comment: No function named `strsep` in the standard library. But good advice to stay clear of `*scanf()`, that noteable is temperamental.

Comment: @DevSolar It's technically a \*BSD extension but it's been widely adopted.  If you don't have it, `strtok_r` has a clunkier interface but approximately the same semantics.

Comment: No function named `strtok_r` in the standard library. (Sorry but I'm pedantic that way. ;-) )

Comment: @DevSolar It's in C99.  If your C library is stuck in 1995, get a real operating system.

Comment: Unfortunately, 1) the current version to aim for is C11, thank you very much, and 2) `strtok_r` is not part of either C99 **nor** C11. It's POSIX.1 (1996). ;-) (<-- notice the smiley there -- absolutely nothing wrong with using `strtok_r`, I am just aiming at the fact that it's not part of the **standard** library.)

Comment: @DevSolar I really thought it was in C99, but I just checked and you're right, it's not even in C11.  (They threw in all the `_s` crap and they didn't pick up POSIX stuff from 1996? Feh.)

Answer (score -1):

You need to use `%[^,]` on your format string to specify the string to copy until `','`.

Exactly like:

```
sscanf(buff1,"%[^,], %[^,], %[^,], %[^,]", netId, netMask, Gateway, Iface);
```

EDIT1:
Thanks to Jonathan's comment `','` is changed to `[^,]` in format string.

Comment: That won't work; the `,` in the data is read as a perfectly good 'not a white space character' and included in the string, and then there isn't a comma left in the input to match the literal comma in the format string.

Answer (score -2):

you simple give the characters you wanna ignore such as comma like this

```
sscanf(buff1,"%s,%s,%s,%s",netId,netMask,Gateway,Iface);
```

to ignore them (not read) , `scanf` and `sscanf` both look for a exact match of whatever you give within the quotes , 
For Example
if you try to read a String as

```
char str[20];
 scanf("hi%s",str);
```

you have to enter the input as '*himystring*', what gets stored in **str** will be '*mystring*',

Hope that Clears it for you !

Comment: The `"%s"` in `sscanf(buff1,"%s,%s...` will consume "11.0.0.0,", _including_ the `','` and then `','` in `sscanf(buff1,"%s,%s...` has nothing to match and `sscanf()` returns 1 without filling in `netMask,Gateway,Iface`.